# How to get better image scaling in Xamarin Forms UWP?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

When an Image element in my app is scaled down by the UI to a small size in UWP, the scaling looks quite bad quality, like it's being scaled via the old "Nearest Neighbor" style which leaves it very pixelated:

[image: UWP Scaling]

When I run the same app on Android, it looks fine:

[image: Android Scaling]

These images are displayed from an URL using the TMDB API. Is there any way to control the image scaling algorithm it's using?

Comment: The resolution depends on the number of pixels per inch on the hardware.  You did not say what machine you are using for the first app.  Only the second app is an Android so I have to assume the first is not Android.  And I have to assume the number of pixels per inch is different on first than the second.

Comment: I said it's UWP, UWP is windows 10. When the resolution is the same, the Android version looks smoother. It appears to be using a better scaling interpolation than the UWP version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get better image scaling in Xamarin Forms UWP?

Please refer UWP image files and performance [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image?view=winrt-19041#image-files-and-performance),  If you are referencing an image file where you know that the source file is a large, high resolution image, but your app is displaying it in a UI region that's smaller than the image's natural size, you should set the `DecodePixelWidth` property, or `DecodePixelHeight`.  For xamarin form project, we suggest you use  [effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction)  to re-render image.

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyCompany")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(ImageFormsTest.UWP.ImageSourceEffect), nameof(ImageEffect))]

public class ImageSourceEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        try
        {
            var control = Control ?? Container;

            if (control is DependencyObject)
            {
                var image = control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image;
                var uri = ImageEffect.GetText(Element);
                var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri)) { DecodePixelHeight = 300, DecodePixelWidth = 600 };

                image.Source = bitmap;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }
 
    protected override void OnDetached()
    {

    }
}
```

**Forms code part**

```
public static class ImageEffect
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
      BindableProperty.CreateAttached("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ImageEffect), string.Empty, propertyChanged: OnTextChanged);

    public static string GetText(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (string)view.GetValue(TextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetText(BindableObject view, string value)
    {
        view.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnTextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var view = bindable as View;
        if (view == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string text = (string)newValue;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            view.Effects.Add(new SourceEffect());
        }
        else
        {
            var toRemove = view.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is SourceEffect);
            if (toRemove != null)
            {
                view.Effects.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        }
    }

}

public class SourceEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public SourceEffect() : base($"MyCompany.{nameof(ImageEffect)}")
    {
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Image
    x:Name="TitleImage" effect:ImageEffect.Text="https://xxxx.jpg"
   />
```

Update

```
public class ImageSourceEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        try
        {
            var control = Control ?? Container;

            if (control is DependencyObject)
            {
                var image = control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image;
                var uri = ImageEffect.GetText(Element);
                var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri));
                bitmap.ImageOpened += Bitmap_ImageOpened;
                image.Source = bitmap;
                image.SizeChanged += Image_SizeChanged;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Image_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bitmapImage != null)
        {
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelType = DecodePixelType.Logical;
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = (int)e.NewSize.Height;
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = (int)e.NewSize.Width;
        }

    }

    private BitmapImage bitmapImage;
    private void Bitmap_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bitmapImage = sender as BitmapImage;
     
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, the UWP version is running in windows, which means people can make the window larger or smaller dynamically, and I don't want to have to rerender or re-decode the image every time they do that. With good filtering, like at bare minimum bilinear interpolation, that shouldn't be necessary. WPF had RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" in their Image control, but I'm struggling to find anything like that in Xamarin or even standalone UWP.

Comment: yep, currently, there is not such option like wpf BitmapScalingMode, so we suggest you set  DecodePixelHeight DecodePixelWidth base on image control size like case update part

Comment: @morphinapg I have updated the case reply with dynamic DecodePixelSize base on the image size changed, Does it work ?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to work, but I need to set the Image's Uri in code, not XAML, since it loads from either the API or my database, plus I only need this on UWP since Android works fine. Right now I'm doing 

ShowImage.SetBinding(ImageEffect.TextProperty, uri.AbsoluteUri);

but that doesn't seem to be doing anything. I've copied ImageEffect into the main project and ImageSourceEffect into the UWP project. I'm assuming that's right? Anything else I need to do?

Comment: If you set the uri in the code-behind, the better solution is make custom render for image control and process the bitmap in the native render, you could refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview).

Comment: Just as a test I tried setting a custom uri in the XAML, and it didn't work either. Seems that it never triggers the OnTextChanged of ImageEffect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231350/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-morphinapg).